# How to set 3d Secure on Magento ? (Err: Centinel API endpoint URL is not configured properly.)

Tags: payment, authorize.net, secure

I have an issue with 3d Secure and Authorize.net on Magento (1.7.02):

Error say:
Centinel API endpoint URL is not configured properly

After some investigation I found out that in the backend you can set value in 
-> Payments Services-> 3D Secure Credit Card Validation.

I really don't know what data should I set here ID for what ?

I also see that in Payment Methods -> Authorize.net there is 3d secure box with **Centinel API URL** should I set this for any reason ? and what value ?

Answer (score 1):

On your authorize.net account there is a spot to get an API. I dont think they call it a centinel API url but its basically just the API url from authorize.net. Make sure you have that option enabled on your Authorize.net account